# Remove undefined or null fields from json by Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

consider following json:

```
const obj = {
   limit: 0,
   lastName: null,
   firstName: 'John',
   age: undefined
}
```

I need to remove lastName and age, and keep limit and firstName. I tried this `_.pickBy(obj, !_.isNil)` but it gives me empty object `{}` and I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

When I tried `_.pickBy(obj, _.isNil)` then keeps lastName and age, which is correct.

Comment: `!_.isNil === false`. Did you mean `x => !_.isNil(x)`?

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `omitBy`:

```js
const obj = {
   limit: 0,
   lastName: null,
   firstName: 'John',
   age: undefined
}

const res = _.omitBy(obj, _.isNil);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @DenisStephanov You are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution to close the question.